# Replace text inside quotes in vim

Tags: vim, regex

I have a large sql file and I would like to rename the table name from `feedback` to `comments` but I don't want to replace the word feedback in case any row has that text so I was trying to select it with the quotes but vim can't find it. I'm using

```
:s/`feedback`/`comments`/
```

Any idea how to do it? maybe vim is not te best option for this?

Comment: You should probably consider something like `sed` or `perl`, but `vim` will do. Shouldn't you use some SQL tool for this? How could you distinguish `feedback` as a table name from `feedback` as a word in content? Or does it come quoted using backticks?

Comment: @muru The sql file has already the backticks. I have never use sed or perl. That's why I tried with Vim

Comment: If they are quoted using backticks, it should work. You can try using the `c` flag (`:s/.../.../c`) to make it confirm each change.

Comment: @muru I tried that `E486: Pattern not found: \`feedback\`` The funny thing is that the word is highlighted now in the editor.

Comment: Did you escape the backticks? I could substitute if I used it as seen in the question, but if I escaped, I get the same error as you and the highlighting happened.

Comment: It's not escaped. I wrote it like I wrote in the question with the `c` modifier you suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18477/discussion-between-serpro-and-muru).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `vim` certainly is capable of doing this, my first thought would be to use [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sed.1.html) or `perl`. Using `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/`feedback`/`comments`/g' path/to/file
```

The `-i` flag makes `sed` perform operations in the files specified instead of writing to `stdout` (`-isuffix` makes a backup copy `path/to/filesuffix`).

Comment: It's also good to use `-i.bak`, so that the original file gets backed up to `path/to/file.bak`.

Answer (score 5):

Try in vim:

```
:%s/`feedback`/`comments`/gc
```

this should work as you expected

Comment: Thanks for your answer That will do the trick too.. I need to check the difference between :s and :%s

Comment: @SERPRO `%` replaces in the entire file. It's an address range for the operation.

Comment: please enter with the quotes. as you wanted

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vi/vim one-liner (using `ex -s` to avoid opening the full screen editor resulting in a short flash):

```
ex -s -c 'w %~ | %s/`feedback`/`comments`/g' -c 'x' <file>
```

Explanation:

- `w %~` saves a copy of the file with the `~` suffix. This is handy as a backup in case you mess up something.
- `|` is the command separator.
- `%` means "do this action on every line".
- `` s/`feedback`/`comments` ``, as you probably already know, means "substitute text matching the regex `` `feedback` `` with `` `comments` `` on the current line".
- `g` means "global", i.e. don't stop after the first substitution on the line.
- `x` is a shorthand for `wq`, i.e. it means write the file and quit. It needs to be separate because otherwise it will hang if there's no match.